# Expanding search bar over specific links

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a search bar that extends over some links. It would expand once you click on an image of a magnify glass that I already have and expand over the "Log In" link. **It does not have to work!** It's just for show.

To get more of an *vision* you can visit my web page [here](http://redsky.incredifull.com) and see where I mean about the *magnify glass* and *login*.

To get even more of a vision of exactly what I'd like, visit [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/26/expanding-search-bar-deconstructed/). This is exactly what I want in every way possible... just more fit to my website. When I download the files, I get confused because there's so many elements to it that I don't need and finding out which ones I don't need is slightly confusing. If someone knows how to de-construct this, it would be perfect.

What I have for my navigation CSS is:

```
/* Navigation bar */
#navi {
height: 40px;
width: 961px;
background: #1e416f;
font-size: 14px;
color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

#navi a:hover {
background: white;
color: #1e416f;
}

#navi .logo {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
float: left;
}

#navi .logo a {
float: left;
width: 56px;
height: 40px;
background: url(/imgs/navi/caul_white_nav.png) center no-repeat;
text-indent: -9999px;
}

#navi .logo a:hover {
background: url(/imgs/navi-hover/caul_blue_nav.png) center no-repeat;
background-color: white;
}

#primary-nav, #tools-nav {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#primary-nav li, #primary-nav a, #tools-nav li, #tools-nav a {
float: left;
}

#primary-nav a, #tools-nav a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 0 10px;
border-right: 1px solid white;
line-height: 40px;
}

#tools-nav a:hover {
color: #1e416f;
}

#primary-nav li:first-child a, #tools-nav li:first-child a {
border-left: 1px solid white;
}

#tools-nav {
float: right;
}

#tools-nav .icon a {
text-indent: -9999px;
}

#tools-nav .email a {
background: url(/imgs/navi/mail.png) no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
width: 20px;
}

#tools-nav .email a:hover {
background: url(/imgs/navi-hover/hover_mail.png) no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
width: 20px;
}

#tools-nav .twitter a {
background: url(/imgs/navi/twitter.png) no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
width: 20px;
}

#tools-nav .twitter a:hover {
background: url(/imgs/navi-hover/hover-twitter.png) no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
width: 20px;
}

#tools-nav .search a {
background: url(/imgs/navi/search.png) no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
width: 20px;
}

#tools-nav .search a:hover {
background: url(/imgs/navi-hover/hover_search.png) no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
width: 20px;
}
```

And my relevant HTML:

```
<!-- NAVIGATION -->
<div id="navi">
<h1 class="logo"><a href="#">CAUL/CBUA</a></h1>

<ul id="primary-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Directories</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Committees</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="tools-nav">
    <li class="login"><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
    <li class="email icon"><a href="#">Email</a></li>
    <li class="twitter icon"><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
    <li class="search icon"><a href="#">Search</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a plugin for this functionality is a few lines of jquery

```
$("#search-icon").click(function(){
    $("#search-field").animate({width: "500px"}, 500).show();
});
```

see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/N8q2J/

EDIT:
so here is what your files should look like
html file where you want to add the search bar

- in the header

  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#search-icon").click(function(){
           $("#search-field").animate({width: "500px"}, 500).show();
      });
  });
- in the body where you want the search bar to be displayed

and the css file add there rules

```
.search-icon{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
}
.search-field{
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 2px;
}
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
.expand{
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: I can see that this works on jsfiddle but if I add it to my site without changing anything at all, it doesn`t work. The only thing that works is the fact that the image is there.

Comment: on the site you have to place the js code between $(document).ready(function(){ ..... }); and off course make sure you have jquery loaded

Comment: What about getting it to expand to the right instead of the left?

Comment: for right to left, you will have to use the animation mentioned below

Answer (score 0):

Well, its quite simple

Put a wrapper around textbox.

```
<div class="textwrapper" style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:300px;width:50px;">
<input type="text" style="width:100%;" />
</div>
```

Note that wrapper has absolute position, so you can position it right next to your search bar.

Initially, put its width to 0

And on click of Searchbar animate it like: (To Open)

```
$('.textwrapper').animate({width: 50, marginLeft: 250}, {duration: 1000});
```

and to close it you can

```
$('.textwrapper').animate({width: 50, marginLeft: 300}, {duration: 1000});
```

This may not work perfectly, but can guide you in right direction.